# Determining Typical Bandwidth for 2.4GHz Radio Control in Drones for FPV Camera Data Transmission

Tags: quadcopters, first-person-view, video-transmitters, fpv-cameras, radio-frequency

I'm working on a drone project that involves transmitting FPV (First Person View) camera data using a 2.4GHz radio control system. I'm trying to calculate the potential delay in transferring this visual data and need some insights into the typical bandwidth available for such systems.

Specifically, I'm interested in understanding the usual bandwidth or data transfer rates achievable through the 2.4GHz radio control transmitters and receivers [commonly used in drones](https://ardupilot.org/plane/docs/common-rc-systems.html). This information is crucial for my calculations related to the time delay in transmitting FPV camera feeds.

Can anyone shed light on the typical bandwidth or provide guidelines regarding the data transfer rates achievable using 2.4GHz radio control systems in drones? Any pointers, personal experiences, or references to specific models/standards would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!